# Install wireless router with cable modem - need authentication server?

Tags: installation, wireless-router, cable

I've bought a wireless router which I'm installing with a Telstra BigPond cable modem for a friend.

As part of the setup I've got to a screen requesting username / password / authentication server for the cable modem

They have contacted Telstra who supply the username / password and say that is all they need. They dont know anything about an authentication server.

There are a couple of answers up on Whirlpool forum found through google but those answers are 4 years old.

- http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies-archive.cfm/475258.html
- http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies-archive.cfm/479615.html

I havent tried them yet as I hoped to get actual answers before trundling over to my friends house again.

Can anyone suggest,

- How to get information from Telstra support? (I realise this question maybe impossible to answer)
- What is the authentication server for Telstra BigPond for a user in Sydney Australia
- Are those whirlpool forum answers still valid?

I guess if I dont get anything more here I'll try what it says on whirlpool and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

for you to contact telstra technical support you can contact this number 133933. or you can go directly to the bigpond website at www.bigpond.com.au. Authentication is needed in order for you to be connected to the net. For the username you need to type in the bigpond email address of your friend and for the password , its the password that your friend created when she set up her account. after supplying those information try to browse a website. I hope it will help.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The problem was the password was not known and their broadband support number was not available after 5pm, which was the only time they had available to call.